# How can I check if my string is other than int's, to clarify i need to check it is not a number

Tags: java, string, if-statement, int

... if instead of a number I get a letter, or a symbol, or 2 decimals.

I am making a change maker program in java.

Everything works good, the only thing i am confused about is checking the string to see if is invalid for my use, 
I did this for when is left empty;

```
         if (s1.isEmpty()) {
             JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input! ");
             System.exit(0);
         }
```

That works perfect, now how can I do the `else` to check for letters or dots or symbols, anything that is not a number?

Comment: What are the valid values for `s1`? Do you only allow single-digit numbers `0...9`?

Comment: Define "number": is it max one decimal point, all digits otherwise?

Comment: Hi and thanks for helping, it is a change maker, so basically my number will be money back so 23.75, as an example

Comment: so first, i want to check if the input is a number instead of letters or symbols or all zeros.

Comment: i already found a way to test for empty, using s1.isEmpty, but dont know how to do it for the other ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to perform all the processing only when the String is integer why  not check for integer value in the if clause and let the else clause be common for all the letter, dots, symbols and also empty.

```
if(s1.isNum){
//all processing here
}

else{
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input");
System.out.exit(0);

}
```

Otherwise you could also use try and catch block.

```
try{
    int num= Integer.parseInt(s1);
    //rest of the processing
    }
catch(Exception e){
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Invalid Input");
System.out.exit(0);
}
```

Use either according to your requirement

Comment: that is genius i think.... the first example i think i can apply. I will work on it now and get back with the results...lol

Answer (score 1):

You could use regular expressions.

Here's some sample code to check for digits only (`\\d`) in your input string.

The code that actually checks is `pattern.matcher(in).matches()` and it tries to match the regular expression defined by `regex`

Let me know if you need more explanations

```
public class HelloWorld{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
        String regex = "\\d+";
        String inputNumber = "2";
        String inputDecimal = "2.0";
        String inputString = "two";

        String[] inputs = {inputDecimal, inputNumber, inputString };

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);

        for(String in: inputs){
            System.out.print( in + " ");
            System.out.print( pattern.matcher(in).matches()? "":"does not");
            System.out.print( " contain integer numbers" );
            System.out.println("---");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [**regular expression**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)<sup>1</sup> and [`String.matches(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) which *Tells whether or not this string matches the given [regular expression](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#sum)*. `\\d+` should match one or more digits. Something like

```
System.out.println("12".matches("\\d+"));
```

Prints

```
true
```

<sup>1<sub>Some people, when confronted with a problem, think
“I know, I'll use regular expressions.”   Now they have two problems.  --[jwz](http://regex.info/blog/2006-09-15/247)</sub></sup>

Answer (score 0):

To test whether it is an integer, parse it to an `int` like this:

```
Integer.parseInt(s1)
```

You might also want to make use of the value returned but I don't show it here. Now you can apply try catch blocks around the method call and catch `NumberFormatException` like this:

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(s1);
    //The code here will run if s1 is an integer.
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //this will be executed when s1 is not an integer
}
```

You can also extract a method from the above code. A method that returns true when the exception is not thrown. However, a disadvantage of try catch is that throwing an exception needs time and thus, it slows down your program.

To test whether the string is a letter, you loop through all the chars in the string and use one of the methods of the `Character` class.

```
boolean isLetter = true;
for (int i = 0 ; i < s1.length() ; i++) {
    if (!Character.isLetter(s1.charAt(i))) {
        isLetter = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

If `isLetter` is true, it is a letter. Again, you can also extract this as a method.

To check whether it is a symbol, use one of the methods of the `Character` class (again).

```
boolean isSymb = true;
for (int i = 0 ; i < s1.length() ; i++) {
    if (!Character.isJavaIdentifierStart(s1.charAt(i))) {
        isSymb = false;
        break;
    }
}
```

To check for dots in a string, just use

```
s1.contains(".")
```

Isn't that simple?

Comment: yes, it looks like it. my only issue is that since is the first project and we just started, we are only using main, so can i still do it?

Comment: Why can't you? I said you _can_ extract the code to create another method but you don't _have_ to do that. Just write the code I wrote in main and check according to my instructions. I never said you need to create another method. But if you do, your code would be _cleaner_. And btw, your first project _can_ contain other methods as well.  So trust me, creating another method wouldn't cost an arm and a leg! Just create it! JUST DO IT!

Comment: is not that i dont want to, is that we have not seen that yet, so i dont want to include stuff we haven t gone over yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I solved the problem the following way... I took a little bit of every idea lol...

```
    if (s1 == null) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    if (s1.isEmpty()) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter a valid integer");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < s1.length(); i = i + 1) {
        if (!Character.isDigit(s1.charAt(i))) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You must enter an integer value");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```